# Multiple values for keyword argument 'question_text'

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error following the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial05/#testing-our-new-view)
 and can't figure out what I am doing differently. Can anyone see the difference between that code and mine below?

```
import datetime

from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from polls.models import Question

class QuestionMethodTests(TestCase):

    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() should return False for questions whose
        pub_date is in the future
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertEqual(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_was_published_recently_with_old_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() should return False for questions whose
        pub_date is older than 1 day
        """
        time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        old_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertEqual(old_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_was_published_recently_with_recent_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() should return True for questions whose
        pub_date is within the last day
        """
        time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        recent_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertEqual(recent_question.was_published_recently(), True)


class QuestionViewTests(TestCase):
    def create_question(question_text, days):
        """
        Creates a question with the given `question_text` published the given
        number of `days` offset to now (negative for questions published
        in the past, positive for questions that have yet to be published).
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
        return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text,
                               pub_date=time)

    def test_index_view_with_no_questions(self):
        """
        If no questions exist, an appropriate message should be displayed.
        """
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

    def test_index_view_with_a_past_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the past should be displayed on the
        index page
        """
        self.create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question.>']
        )

     def test_index_view_with_a_future_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the future should not be displayed on
        the index page.
        """
        self.create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.",
                            status_code=200)
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

    def test_index_view_with_future_question_and_past_question(self):
        """
        Even if both past and future questions exist, only past questions
        should be displayed.
        """
        self.create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
        self.create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question.>']
        )

    def test_index_view_with_two_past_questions(self):
        """
        The questions index page may display multiple questions.
        """
        self.create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
        self.create_question(question_text="Past question 2.", days=-5)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>']
        )
```

Full Error:
[image]

Comment: What is the error? Please post a description of the error and a traceback.

Comment: Hope you can see the error OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_question` is an instance method, it should have a `self` as the first parameter:

```
def create_question(self, question_text, days):
                    ^^^^
```

or, define it as a staticmethod or a classmethod if you don't need to access instance attributes.

```
@staticmethod
def create_question(question_text, days):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method:

```
def create_question(question_text, days):
```

Needs `self` as the first parameter. The method will be called with the instance as the first argument, and if you try to pass another argument with the same name, you get your error message.

i.e., use

```
def create_question(self, question_text, days):
```

instead.